# Writing mutation graphql-client c#

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet, graphqlclient

I tried to write mutation but it gives me error.
as `{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Expected $, found Name \"objects\"","locations":[{"line":2,"column":27}],"extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED"}}]}`

The code I wrote is this.

```
        [HttpGet("GraphDataCreate")]
        public async Task<dynamic> ReturnGraphDataCreate()
        {
            using var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("https://api.spacex.land/graphql/", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
            var trial = new GraphQLRequest
            {
                Query = @"
                query insert_users(objects: { name: $name, rocket: $rocket }) {
                    returning {
                        id
                        name
                        rocket
                        timestamp
                        twitter
                    }
                }",
                OperationName = "insert_users",
                Variables = new
                {
                    name = "AdiAntNam",
                    rocket = "SPUTNIK5V"
                }
            };
            var graphQLResponse = (object)(null);
            try
            {
                graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(trial);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var err = ex;
                string err1 = ex.Message;
                string err2 = ex.InnerException.Message;                
            }
            return Task.FromResult(graphQLResponse);
        }
```

Now what is it I'm missing in this part ?
The reference I've taken is from here. 
https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the example is the data type which is written that is hard to follow `PersonAndFilms($id: ID)` now **ID** is a data type so I was assuming that it was just a variable name declared that's why I was in confusion.

So I had written it as query `insert_users(objects: { name: $name, rocket: $rocket })` which was not understandable for GraphQL as it requires Data Type, so I re-writed my query as below.

```
var trial = new GraphQLRequest
            {
                Query = @"
                mutation xyz($nameU: String, $rocketU: String)
                {
                    insert_users(objects: { name: $nameU , rocket: $rocketU }) 
                    {
                        returning 
                        {
                            id
                            name
                            rocket
                            timestamp
                            twitter
                        }
                    }
                }",
                OperationName = "xyz",
                Variables = new
                {
                    nameU = "AdiAntNam2",
                    rocketU = "SPUTNIK5V"
                }
            };
```

Now the mutation `xyz($nameU: String, $rocketU: String)` it reads correct data type. The example is correct some what in the project but confusing to end user as `$id: ID` is not much understandable so its better to use example as mine.

Comment: Why did you change the OperationName to xyz? I am also new to adding new items using GraphQL

Comment: I also see you are using String for the type declaration. Would you also use Boolean and Integer for the other types?

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer please look into this URL - https://api.spacex.land/graphql/ as some of the arguments require String type and some require Boolean and Integer.

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer as that part required String only for now.

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer xyz only for knowing that you can write anything beside name.

Comment: How did you determine what to put into the returning field? I know mine returns a AccountUser with fields like id, firstName, lastName, userName, email, and etc. Do I need to put returning accountUser.

Comment: https://api.spacex.land/graphql/ check the mutation in the explorer tab select `insert_users` then options will be there.

Comment: @Namco When I navigated to the https://api.spacex.land/graphql/ website  I can Only see generation of sample query code.  I do Not see any option for mutation or insert or update.  Could you please advise?